# C# : Unable to add an existing dictionary object to viewmodel object

Tags: c#

I am implementing a viewmodel in my c# controller and having issue with adding a populated dictionary to the viewmodel object

My viewmodel FundPerformanceVM is as follows

```
public class FundPerformanceVM
    {
        public FundPerformanceVM()
        {
            TrackRecord = new List<TrackRecordVM>();
        }

        public int FundId { get; set; }
        public string FundName { get; set; }
        public List<TrackRecordVM> TrackRecord { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<string, double, double>>> FundStatistics { get; set; }

    }
```

Following is the code where i am populating the viewmodel. If you notice i am calling

```
 fundStatistics = GetRiskMatrixByFunds(fundPerformance);
```

I need to add this to the viewmodel object. I am gettting error when i do

```
 fundPerformance.Add(fundStatistics);
```

GetFundPerformance method

```
private List<FundPerformanceVM> GetFundPerformance(Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<FUND_PERFORMANCE>> allPerformance, DateTime currentMonth)
        {
            var fundPerformance = new List<FundPerformanceVM>();
            Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<string, double, double>>> fundStatistics;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<FUND_PERFORMANCE>> entry in allPerformance)
            {
                var lastRecord = entry.Value.Where(x => x.VALUEDATE <= currentMonth).FirstOrDefault();
                if (lastRecord == null) continue;

                var performance = entry.Value.GroupBy(x => x.VALUEDATE.Year).ToList();
                var fundTrackRecord = new FundPerformanceVM();
                fundTrackRecord.FundId = entry.Key;
                fundTrackRecord.FundName = entry.Value.FirstOrDefault() != null ? entry.Value.FirstOrDefault().TRACK_RECORD_HEADER.FUND.NAME_TEXT : string.Empty;

                if (!performance.Any()) return fundPerformance;

                foreach (var p in performance)
                {
                    var model = new TrackRecordVM
                    {
                        Year = p.Key,
                        Jan = (double?)(p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 1) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 1).MTD : null),
                        Feb = (double?)(p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 2) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 2).MTD : null),
                        Mar = (double?)(p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 3) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 3).MTD : null),
                        Apr = (double?)(p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 4) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 4).MTD : null),
                        May = (double?)(p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 5) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 5).MTD : null),
                        Jun = (double?)(p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 6) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 6).MTD : null),
                        Jul = (double?)(p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 7) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 7).MTD : null),
                        Aug = (double?)(p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 8) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 8).MTD : null),
                        Sep = (double?)(p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 9) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 9).MTD : null),
                        Oct = (double?)(p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 10) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 10).MTD : null),
                        Nov = (double?)(p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 11) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 11).MTD : null),
                        Dec = (double?)(p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 12) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 12).MTD : null),
                        YTD = (double?)(p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 12) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 12).YTD : null),
                        Bmrk = (double?)(p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 12) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 12).BENCHMK1_MTD : null),
                        BmrkName = p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 12) != null ? p.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VALUEDATE.Month == 12).BENCHMK1_INDEX_NAME : null
                    };

                    fundTrackRecord.TrackRecord.Add(model);
                }

                fundPerformance.Add(fundTrackRecord);
                fundStatistics = GetRiskMatrixByFunds(fundPerformance);

                fundPerformance.Add(fundStatistics);
            }
            return fundPerformance;
        }
```

GetRiskMatrixByFunds method

```
         private Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<string, double, double>>> GetRiskMatrixByFunds(List<FundPerformanceVM> fundTrackRecord)
        {

            Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<double>> returnsList = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<double>>();
            Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<string, double, double>>> list = new Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<string, double, double>>>();
            List<Tuple<string, double, double>> list1 = null;
            RiskMatrix riskMatrix = new RiskMatrix();
            List<TrackRecordVM> trackRecordVm;
            int fundId;
            (double Monthly, double Annual) arithmeticMean;
            (double Monthly, double Annual) averageGain;
            (double Monthly, double Annual) averageLoss;



            foreach (var trackRecord in fundTrackRecord)
            {
                trackRecordVm = trackRecord.TrackRecord;
                fundId = trackRecord.FundId;

                var jan = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Jan).ToList();
                var feb = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Feb).ToList();
                var mar = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Mar).ToList();
                var apr = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Apr).ToList();
                var may = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.May).ToList();
                var jun = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Jun).ToList();
                var jul = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Jul).ToList();
                var aug = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Aug).ToList();
                var sep = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Sep).ToList();
                var oct = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Oct).ToList();
                var nov = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Nov).ToList();
                var dec = trackRecordVm.Select(x => x.Dec).ToList();

                var monthData = new List<double?>();
                monthData.AddRange(jan);
                monthData.AddRange(feb);
                monthData.AddRange(mar);
                monthData.AddRange(apr);
                monthData.AddRange(may);
                monthData.AddRange(jun);
                monthData.AddRange(jul);
                monthData.AddRange(aug);
                monthData.AddRange(sep);
                monthData.AddRange(oct);
                monthData.AddRange(nov);
                monthData.AddRange(dec);


                var finalMonthList = monthData.Where(f => f.HasValue).Select(f => f.Value);

                returnsList.Add(fundId, finalMonthList);


            }
```

Comment: Please, add the error message so we can take a look

Comment: `fundPerformance` is a list of VM's `fundStatitics` is dictionary.

Comment: cannot convert Dictionary to FundPerformanceVM

Answer (score 2):

Look at the data types implied by your usage:

```
fundStatistics = GetRiskMatrixByFunds(fundPerformance);
```

`fundStatistics` is therefore a `Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<string, double, double>>>`, and `fundPerformance` is a `List<FundPerformanceVM>`

```
fundPerformance.Add(fundStatistics);
```

You are trying to add a `Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<string, double, double>>>` to a `List<FundPerformanceVM>` which is obviously not allowed.

It's not clear what the relationships between these variables and the properties of the 
`FundPerformanceVM` class are to know what to change to get it to even *compile*.

Comment: I have the following code in my controller if that helps . I am building the viewmodel here and passing to the client  var vm = new ManagerStrategyPerformanceVM
            {
                SummaryPerformance = CreateViewModel(allPerformance, currentMonth),
                FundPerformance = GetFundPerformance(allPerformance, currentMonth)
            };

            return vm;

Comment: So as you can see GetFundPerformance returns a list of type  List<FundPerformanceVM>. It will return trackrecord and statistics with every element in the list

Comment: Sorry, but the relationships are still not obvious, nor is it clear why you need to add the returned value to the original list. Hopefully you see the reason for the error, but I don't see an obvious solution.